# matplotlib pyplot table with non-ascii data?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a table figure in png.

The data in the table contains non-ascii characters.(suppose it's chinese or something)

I pass unicode code-points (u'hello') to pyplot and it shows the characters as squares.

Comment: What context? As labels, as text, otherwise? Also: what Python version (2 or 3) may be relevant here. Last: **show us your code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be (slightly) platform dependent, but I prefer to use `unicode` for Chinese and other languages. One other thing is that you need to make sure is `matplotlib` must get the necessary font. You can do it anywhere you need a `text` except sometimes not with `mathtext`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
zhfont1 = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname='/Library/Fonts/Kai.dfont') #I am on OSX.
s=u'\u54c8\u54c8' #Need the unicode for your Chinese Char.
plt.text(0.5,0.5,s,fontproperties=zhfont1, size=50) #example: plt.text()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

another method is to modify the file /matplotlibrc/  on your matplotlib system.

Find this line

`#font.sans-serif`

and add your font in this line.

And then you need to add the font-file into the font directory of matplotlib.

Here I give this two paths:

1. ~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data
2. $HOME.matplotlib\fontList.cache

PS: Windows 7.